# How to force loading images for the webpages installed "lazy load" without scrolling?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, lazy-loading

I implement a Chrome extension. The extension needs to get all images URLs of webpages. However, some webpages have "lazy load" plug-in.
My question is if it is possible that I can still get URLs without required manually scrolling down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the lazy-load plugins stores the actual URL in the data-* section. When scrolling down, right before the image tag gets into view the data-* content is set on the `src` attribute to start loading the image.

You can iterate through all the image tags like this to find the links, for example:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img"),
    links = [], i = 0, img;

while(img = images[i++]) 
    links.push(img.dataset.original || img.src);
```

But note that there is no naming standard for the data-* holder so different plugins will use different names - you'll have to collect these manually (f.ex. [this plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) uses the name `data-original`, [this one](https://github.com/callmecavs/layzr.js) uses `data-layzr` and so on).

You could possible do an addition step looping through the `dataset` collection to find any string which may seem to contain an URL (if `src` is empty), but also this is prone to errors as images from the same server often are relative links and data-* can hold other data too.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code you can trigger the 'appear' event event on all the images.

```
$('img').trigger('appear');
```

Would help if you would privde a jsfiddle to test on.