# How to force/trigger the load of Wordpress native lazy loading images without scrolling?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lazy-loading, pagespeed

I don't like lazy-loading because it looks quite ugly for the user in terms of UX. However, I understand the benefits (faster page load, low bandwidth, high PageSpeed scores etc.)

I am planning to write a javascript code which will:

Stay in the bottom > Wait for the page to fully load > After 3 seconds it will work > Force load all the images which were lazy-loaded previously during initial page load

With this, I won't lose any speed scores (because it will load as normal with lazy loaded images) But, also will load the full images when everything is done, so user won't notice. (we do the same for loading live chat scripts. It works pretty nice)

It will probably look something like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var ForceLoadImages = document.createElement('script');
        ForceLoadImages.type = 'text/javascript';
        ForceLoadImages.src = 'link-to-the-script-to-force-load-images.js';
        document.body.appendChild(chatScript);
    }, 3000);
};
</script>
```

I am not a js expert. This was just a dummy example to give an idea. I am specifically asking how to write the content of that "link-to-the-script-to-force-load-images.js" part. Will appreciate any inputs.

*There was a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839469/how-to-force-loading-images-for-the-webpages-installed-lazy-load-without-scrol), but need an answer for Wordpress.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the wp lazy load uses `data-src` attribute to hold the image and when in view port, its adding the image to the `src` attribute.

Simplified like this:

```
<img data-src="URL"/>
```

*if its not like this, find in your source code the attribute where image is hold when out of view

What you need to do is select all images and change the `data-src` to `src` like this:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

window.onload = function() {
setTimeout(function(){ 
for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    if(images[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
       images[i].setAttribute('src',images[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
       images[i].removeAttribute('data-src'); // optional if you need to remove data-src attribute after setting src
    }
}
}, 3000);
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img data-src='https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300' />
<img data-src='https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300' />
<img data-src='https://picsum.photos/200/300' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! With a litle bit modification I made it work. Actually, Wordpress places loading="lazy" attribute to the images during page load. Just removing this attribute made the magic! Let me add this also to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to put the solution as an answer ([thanks to kaize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64928254/4131419)) who are looking for something like this. It is very clean and works nice:

```js
<script>
var loadimages = document.querySelectorAll('img');
window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout(function(){
      //Force Load images
      for (var i=0; i<loadimages.length; i++) {
         if(loadimages[i].getAttribute('loading')) {
            loadimages[i].removeAttribute('loading');
         }
      }
   }, 3000);
};
</script>
```

**Who is this for?**
For those who does not like the user-experience of lazy loading images. But applying it due to PageSpeed scores.

**Where to place this?**
Place this to the bottom of your page.

**What does this script do?**
This script runs 3 seconds after the page loaded completely. It force-loads all the images which were waiting to get into the viewport to be lazy-loaded by removing the "loading" attribute. So that, you get good pagespeed scores for deferring image loads meanwhile keeping the user experience better. *(Keep in mind that you lose the bandwidth advantage of lazy-loading concept)*